# ServiceStack OrmLite "Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime time columntype"

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

When performing  a `OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.CreateTable()` in MS LocalDB or SQL2012 this is translated to a `TIME(7)` db column type. As a result when inserting data using `OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.SaveAll()` we get the following error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildParamList(TdsParser parser, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildExecuteSql(CommandBehavior behavior, String commandText, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ExecNonQuery(IDbCommand dbCmd)
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExtensions.Insert[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, T obj, Boolean selectIdentity)
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExtensions.SaveAll[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, IEnumerable`1 objs)
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5d`1.<SaveAll>b__5c(IDbCommand dbCmd)
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadConnectionExtensions.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.SaveAll[T](IDbConnection dbConn, IEnumerable`1 objs)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
```

Although I appreciate we can work round this I would have expected OrmLite to map TimeSpans as part of the OrmLite dialect, perhaps even storing as ticks? I'm no sure it should be necessary to implement an IConvertible to resolve this.

*NB: We intentionally use TimeSpan C# types in our data-models to represent fields that only signify times and not dates, as to make usage explicit.*

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the same problem, Demis has now published an update in 4.0.8 that gives support for TimeSpan's across all providers.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/15